# Need a simple example of a type that includes units

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a codebase that deals with angles quite a bit, but sometimes the input comes in different angle formats.  That is, some formats are degrees clockwise, some are degrees counter-clockwise, some are 0 to 360, some are -180 to 180, some are radians...

So far I have succeeded in keeping them all the same internally, but it's always a worry, and the bugs that arise can be hard to track down.

I would like to create an angle class that keeps track of the units and direction as well as the magnitude so that I can deal with them in a uniform way without so much worries.

My googling has turned up Martin Fowler's [Value Object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html), but i'm having trouble understanding his language without a simple example to reference.  I've also found a [Java API](http://www.unitsofmeasurement.org/) that seems relevant, but it doesn't look like a *simple* example either...

Can anyone point me towards a simple example of a class that incorporates units?

Comment: Do you need to remember the original unit, or would it be okay to convert everything to a common unit inside the class?

Comment: I would like to be able to both store and retrieve the angle in a variety of units.  I don't know if it would be better to convert to one unit inside the class and provide conversion on the accessors or to save the unit (and then also to conditional conversion on the accessors...?)

Comment: Can you also elaborate on "a variety of units"? Do you have more units than just degrees and radians?

Comment: I have degrees & radians, but that's not what prompted me to try and make an angle class.  The major info that I need to convert between right now is clockwise=positive vs. clockwise=negative, or left-handed vs. right-handed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by storing values internally in a single format (say, positive radians) and provide static factory methods to construct angles from various input formats. For example:

```
public class Angle {
  private final double radians;

  private Angle(double radians) {
    this.radians = radians;
  }

  // Static factory methods

  public static Angle radians(double rad) {
    return new Angle(rad);
  }

  public static Angle degrees(double deg) {
    return radians(Math.toRadians(deg));
  }

  public static Angle degreesCCW(double deg) {
    return degrees(360 - deg);
  }

  ...

  // Operations

  public Angle plus(Angle other) {
    return new Angle((this.radians + other.radians) % (2 * Math.PI));
  }

  ...
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
Angle a1 = Angle.radians(0.5);
Angle a2 = Angle.degreesCCW(60);
Angle a3 = a1.plus(a2);
```

Answer (score 1):

[scala's Duration](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.util.Duration) is a nice example, as it accepts numbers in various units (seconds, milliseconds, etc).  Not sure how that might translate into another language, but there's a chance.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
class Measurement
{
    double amount;
    Unit   unit;
}
```

amount will be the "number", and unit will tell you how to interpret that number... You might also need to implement some logic in the numbers, or a "Table conversion" to be able to convert between different units...

BTW: 
This is a great library implementing that in Smalltalk: [Aconcagua](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aconcagua/). It has a [paper](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/Teaching/CoursAnnecy/0506-M1-COO/aconcagua-p292-wilkinson.pdf) too.
This is another very good one in C++: [Boost units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_units.html).